# My question was closed

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I wonder why my post was closed.

My question was: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57172/a-few-possible-answers-in-the-test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was closed as "too localized".

The blurb says:

> This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. See the [FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#close).

First, your question isn't very clear. I don't really know what it's asking.

Second, it looks like your question is very specific to your test and won't be useful to anyone else in the future.

You may have better luck if make it clearer what you are asking, and make it more general so it's not specifically about a test.

Comment: Hello,  The answer could help me :D. Anyway,  I don't't want to waste my time on here. Please delete my profile.

Comment: Here's instructions on how to delete your account: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account

Comment: Here's the thing, @Monica, Stack Exchange doesn't say "well, so long as the answer helps one person, that's good enough" it says "unless we can help lots of people, the question is not good enough".

Comment: @Monica Why do you want to delete it?